# How could I validate forms using my JS regex file while doing the rest of the back end work with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, validation

I have done my research and I tried reading the PHP manual on the `preg_match()` function and still quite don't understand as the Boolean keeps returning false. Then I had came up with a plausible solution however, I couldn't find anything searchable through the phrase of my question.

I have a JavaScript file with regex expressions inputting responsive data to the users for my front end. However, I still want the button to work making PHP produce the error itself IE my back end.

My file structure would consist of something like: 'contact.php', 'regex.js', and, 'validateContact.php'. I want validateContact.php to be able to detect if regex.js is returning false and produce the error through validateContact.php

So my question, how would I be able to do this?

contact.php

```
<?php 

        $pageTitle  = "Contact"; 
        $section    = "contact";

?>

<?php include 'INC/header.php'; ?>

    <div class="container">

        <h1 class="text-center"> <u> Contact Us </u> </h1>

    <p class="text-justify"> 
        Feel free to contact us about any of your design or development 
        needs. We will be happy to schedule a personal consultant to discuss 
        any questions you may have and to create a plan for your project, 
        Or you can able request a free quote. Please be specific as possible 
        with your specifications and we will be happy to provide you with an
        estimate. 
    </p>

    <p class="text-justify">
        We are available most weekday mornings through the evenings and will respond
        to all messages within 48 hours. As always, we are not into
        high-pressure sales, but are here to help and service your needs.
    </p>

        <!-- insert captcha to protect from bots/spammers -->
        <div class="container">

            <form action="verifyContact.php" method="POST">
            <!-- Have client put in name for information reasons -->

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">

                        <!-- Bootstrap Validation -->
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                        <label for="name"> Name </label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" onkeyup="validateName()" id="name" class="form-control"  placeholder="Full Name" />
                        <label id="namePrompt"></label>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Have client input phone number so we can call them -->
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i>
                <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="phone" onkeyup="validatePhone()" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Number">
                <label id="phonePrompt"></label>



                <!-- Have client input email for contacting reaons -->
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" onkeyup="validateEmail()" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
                <label id="emailPrompt"></label>



                <label for="question">Comments or Questions:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="comments" onkeyup="validateQuestion()" id="question" rows="3"></textarea>
                <label id="questionPrompt"></label>
                <br/>

                <img src="generate.php" /> 
                <br />
                <label for="security"> Please input the number you see above</label>
                <input type="text" size="6" name="security" onkeyup="validateSecurity()" id="security" />
                <label id="securityPrompt"></label>
                <br />

                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

            </form>

    <!--Faster Loadtime-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/regex.js"></script>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

<?php include 'INC/footer.php'; ?>
```

verifyContact.php

```
<?php $pageTitle = "Thanks for contacting Infinity Desing"; ?>
<?php include 'INC/header.php'; ?>

<?php 

        $submit     = $_POST['submit'];
        $name       = $_POST['name'];
        $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
        $email      = $_POST['email'];
        $comments   = $_POST['comments'];
        $security   = $_POST['security'];

        $namePattern = "Domnick Knowlton";

        if ($name && $phone && $email & $comments && $security)
        {

            if (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z]*\s{1}[A-Za-z]*$/i', $namePattern))
            {

                echo "Thanks";

            } else echo "<h1 class='text-center'> <span class='alert alert-warning'> A <b>First</b> and <b>Last</b> name is required!</h1> </span>"; 

        } else echo "<h1 class='text-center'> <span class='alert alert-warning'> Please fill out <b>All</b> fields!</h1> </span>";
?>

<?php include 'INC/footer.php'; ?>
```

regex.js

```
function validateName()
{

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

    if (name.length == 0)
    {

        producePrompt("Your full name is required", "namePrompt", "#FF0033");
        return false;

    }

    if (!name.match(/^[A-Za-z]*\s{1}[A-Za-z]*$/))
        {

            producePrompt("A first name and last name is required", "namePrompt", "#FF0033");
            return false;

        }

    producePrompt("Thanks, " + name, "namePrompt", "#61B329");
    return true;

}

function validatePhone() 
{

    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;

    if (phone.length == 0)
    {

        producePrompt("Your phone number is required", "phonePrompt", "#FF0033");
        return false;

    }

    if (!phone.match(/^(\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3}-)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/))
    {

        producePrompt("Pleas only include parethesis and or hyphens (XXX)XXX-XXXX", "phonePrompt", "#FF0033");
        return false;

    }

    producePrompt("Valid Number", "phonePrompt", "#61B329");
    return true;

}

function validateEmail()
{

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

    if (email.length == 0)
    {

        producePrompt("Your E-Mail is required", "emailPrompt", "#FF0033");
        return false;

    }

    if (!email.match(/^(([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])|([-]|[_]|[.]))+[@](([a-zA-Z0-9])|([-])){2,63}[.](([a-zA-Z0-9]){2,63})+$/))
    {

        producePrompt("Invalid E-Mail Adress", "emailPrompt", "#FF0033");
        return false;

    }

    producePrompt("Valid E-Mail Address", "emailPrompt", "#61B329");
    return true;

}

function validateQuestion()
{

    var comment     = document.getElementById("question").value;
    var required    = 25;
    var left        = required - comment.length;

    if (left > 0)
    {

        producePrompt(left + " Characters Required", "questionPrompt", "#FF0033");
        return false;

    }

    producePrompt("We'll be sure to get to you shortly!", "questionPrompt", "#61B329");
    return true;

}

function validateSecurity()
{

    var security = document.getElementById("security").value;

    if (security.length == 0)
    {

        producePrompt("Please fill out the captcha", "securityPrompt", "#FF0033");
        return false;

    }

    if (!security.match(/[0-9]{1,3}/))
    {

        producePrompt("The captcha only needs 1-3 numbers!", "securityPrompt", "#FF0033");
        return false;

    }

    producePrompt("Thank you for contacting Infinity Design!", "securityPrompt", "#61B329");
    return true;

}

function producePrompt(message, promptlocation, color)
{

    document.getElementById(promptlocation).innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById(promptlocation).style.color = color;

}
```

I don't know if this would help but the output is thanks. No matter what the input is on the name.

Comment: Are you trying to validate email input with php and `preg_match()` ?

Comment: sounds like you just need to tweak your php regexp; the extra escaping and string instead of literal format can be confusing and a pain to get debugged.